# convert a Dataframe of date objects to datetime

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, object

```
print(data["Date Time"]
```

[image]

```
data["Date Time"] = data["Date Time"].str.replace("Verkauft","")

print(data["Date Time"]
```

[image]

> above DataFrame is dtype: object

i want to convert into datetime to use it for visualization

```
data["Date Time"] = pd.to_datetime(data["Date Time"],format="%d%M%Y")
```

Error Output:

[image]

**Update:**

i added:

```
data["Date Time"] = data["Date Time"].str.replace("  ","")
```

because the output shows blank characters. however, it did not help.

Output:

[image]

Comment: Replace `data["Date Time"].str.replace("  ","")` by `data["Date Time"].str.strip()`

Comment: Please post text instead of screenshots. Copy and paste is much better than OCR for somebody that wants to provide an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove `format=` to let the function determine the right format:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'Date Time': ['1. Sep 2021']})
data['Date Time'] = pd.to_datetime(data["Date Time"])
print(data)

# Output:
   Date Time
0 2021-09-01
```

**Update**:

> I got error again: "Unknown string format: %s, timestt"

To debug, find rows where dates have not a right format:

```
data.loc[pd.to_datetime(data['Date Time'], errors='coerce').isna(), 'Date Time']
```

Comment: i got error again: "Unkown string format: %s, timestt"

Comment: @mika. I updated my answer to help you to find errors

Comment: thank you for you help i treid again and got the same error i will add it in my question, mabe it helps.

Comment: i have to add that i remove the spaces in the dataframe, you see that in the output of my question.

Comment: u updated my question. the output is with you funcion above

Comment: Why did you remove space? How Pandas can parse dates now?

Comment: whe you look at my Questin you see that '    29. Sep 2021' i fix it to '29. Sep 2021'

Comment: in the comments it is not clear. But you can see it in the picture that "BEFORE" the 29 are spaces

Comment: Use `strip` rather than `replace`. See my comment on your post.

Comment: yea i did, i got the same error

Comment: maybe dataframe got probelms with the NaN ? i added dropna but the Dataframe didnt drop it ?

Comment: got it it was a problem with the .csv file.   in one row i got again "Date TIme"-string. removed and i got converted datetime